Embeded map with search bar using GeoNode
I try to embed a map and enable the "search" plugin by adding the script to _geonode_config.html
{% extends 'geonode-mapstore-client/_geonode_config.html' %}
{% block override_local_config %}

<script> window.__GEONODE_CONFIG__.overrideLocalConfig = function(localConfig, _) { { localconfig.plugins.map_embed.push({ "name": "search" }); return localConfig; }; </script>
{% endblock %}

It is fine but the location of search bar overalaps with layer button at left top corner. How can I put the search bar to right top corner?
